# Work both with VS 2010 and VS 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I need to know whether can I use VS 2010 and VS 2012 both on same machine.

- That means, I am having projects which are running MVC 2 with vs 2010.
- So then when I install vs 2012 on my machine will it effect the projects which I am running on vs 2010.
- In other words I need to work both versions time to time.According to the projects.
- I don't have any idea to convert MVC 2 projects into MVC 4 or compatible with vs 2012.
- When I need to work with vs 2010 project I have to have that freedom.

So Can I do this after installing vs 2012 on my laptop.

Comment: You can use MVC2 with VS 2010 and 2012. Just don't upgrade your projects to .NET 4.5.

Comment: Why would you expect any problems? VS2010 and VS2012 are independent programs, why would they affect each other?

Comment: @jrummell I would like better to use vs 2010 for my MVC 2 projects rather than opening it with vs 2012.So can I do that after installing vs 2012 ?

Comment: @svick B'cos I had really bad issues with vs 2008 and vs 2010.So that is the case I have raised this question before installing the vs 2012.If something will go wrong for my existing projects it will give huge problem for me.I would like to share your experience here with vs 2010 and vs 2012.

Comment: @Sampath: I used VS2005 and VS2010 alongside each other for a while and had no problems. What issues did you experience?

Comment: @svick It's not exactly out of the question for some issues to occur. A VS install isn't really a self-contained app but a tangled mess of related components of which a good deal are registered globally for automation purposes. (That said were this question merely "will I encounter problems when running both" it wouldn't be a good question.)

Comment: You should be able to work with VS2010 projects from a VS2012 install without problems or without an incompatible project metadata upgrade if you don't touch the framework settings. (And install MVC2 support for VS2012 if it's not there by default.) There really shouldn't be a need to keep both around.

Comment: @jrummell Why did you remove your answer.I came here for accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find VS2010 and VS2012 coexist on the same machine just fine.

Comment: That means after installing vs 2012 can I open mvc 2 projects with vs 2010 ? B'cos i need vs 2012 only for new projects.

Comment: Your file associations might get messed up after installing VS2012 but that's fairly easy to fix. Make sure you open your project in VS2010. If you do open it in VS2012 then do NOT convert your project to the new version if you still want to be able to open it in VS2010 later.

Answer (score 1):

No it will not effect any project.

Yes you can just open your project with VS 2012 so far as I know there are no code changes between VS 2010 and VS 2012.

Yes you can use both versions on the same machine I am also doing that.

Make sure you backup your stuff before anything goes wrong.

Comment: That means after installing vs 2012 can I open mvc 2 projects with vs 2010 ? B'cos i need vs 2012 only for new projects.

Comment: Yes you can use both editors by using the version selector or just open the editor you want and open the project.